# Can `SendChannel.offer`, `CompletableDeferred.complete`, and similar be called outside coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

`CompletableDeferred` documentation says

> All functions on this interface and on all interfaces derived from it are thread-safe and can be safely invoked from concurrent coroutines without external synchronization.

Is it safe to call these functions outside any coroutine?

For `SendChannel<E>`, `offer` and `close` are not `suspend` and so they can be called outside coroutines syntactically, but is it actually safe to do so?

If a coroutine *is* needed, what is the cheapest way to start one: `launch(Unconfined)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to call `offer` and `close` from anywhere. That is what documentation means to say with "are thread-safe" phrase.

One of the reasons these methods are included into channel APIs is to enable integration of coroutines with the regular non-coroutine world that is based on various callbacks and event handlers. You can see the actual example of such integration in this [guide on UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md).